# copy sqlite database to Data folder

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm creating a dictionary app. My Sqlite database is about 15MB and on the first startup I copy it to the Data folder. I do this in the `onCreate` Method in the main activity. While copying is in process, the user sees a black screen. I want my app to run and the user to see the main activity and only then have the database copy process start! How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and do the work there.

It will do the copying on another thread leaving the UI thread free to interact with the user.

It is recommended that you do all heavy work outside the UI thread or your app might become unresponsive.

Answer (score 1):

you gotta create a AsyncTask to do that, following post explains that.

http://www.androidsnippets.com/download-an-http-file-to-sdcard-with-progress-notification